# how to Running Flask with Apache2 and Mod-WSGI

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask, raspberry-pi3, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to Running Flask with Apache2 and Mod-WSGI in my raspberry I got The requested URL that was not found on this server I try to edit 000-default.conf but app won't with Mod-WSGI.
I used python 3

can someone let me know what is the problem?

thank you
this is my status from apache2:

[image]

this is app.wsgi :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/prox')
from init import app as application
```

this is 000-default.conf

```
Listen 5000
```

<VirtualHost *:5000>

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prox

    LogLevel debug

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/prox/app.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess prox processes=5 threads=1 user=pi group=pi display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup prox
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIChunkedRequest On
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-5000.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-5000.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/prox>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
```

this the app: named app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

app.debug = True
if __name__ == '__main__'
    app.run()
```

this is journalctl -xe :
[image]

I got this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the flask app itself on your apache server, for example.

```
// Find your flask app
export FLASK_APP=<YOUR_FILE>

// Host it on your local network
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

This will start the server, makes sure you are in the virtual environment and directory your flask app is stored in.

Comment: Hi thank you i try it but i got error : File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Comment: Perhaps the port is still used by the server of apache. While in the sites-available file of your apache installation run `sudo a2dissitite 000-default.conf` and `sudo a2dissite <your app conf>. From there reload apache with sudo service apache2 restart. While there make sure your wsgi is up to date by running `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 -y' Hope it helps